# How can I get my pyinstaller compiled app to run by a user with standard privileges?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

So I wrote this Letter Generator app and compiled it with pyinstaller. The executable file works just fine on my end, but the app doesn't work for a non-administrative user, when opened it says "LetterGen can't be executed". Anyway I can get this app to work on a standard user account?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys
import os
if os.path.exists("Letter.rtf"):
  os.remove("Letter.rtf")

def save_info():
    Date_info = Date.get()
    ExistingCardType_info = ExistingCardType.get()
    RequestedCardType_info = RequestedCardType.get()
    Name_info = Name.get()
    IDCard_info = IDCard.get()
    Address_info = Address.get()
    Island_info = Island.get()
    PhoneNo_info = PhoneNo.get()

    filename = 'C:\\Users\\Pain\\Desktop\data\\New folder\\data.txt'
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        filename2 = "Letter.rtf"
        with open(filename2, 'w') as f1:
          text = f.read()
          text = re.sub('string_replace1', Date_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace2', ExistingCardType_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace3', RequestedCardType_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace4', Name_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace5', IDCard_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace6', Address_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace7', Island_info, text)
          text = re.sub('string_replace8', PhoneNo_info, text)
          f1.seek(0)
          f1.write(text)
          f1.truncate()
          messagebox.showinfo("Message", "Letter Generated.")
          os.startfile("Letter.rtf")

def about():
   messagebox.showinfo( "About", "Written by U2816.")

app = Tk()

app.iconbitmap(r'C:\Users\Pain\Desktop\data\New folder\icon.ico')

app.resizable(False, False)

app.geometry("315x400")

app.title("LetterGen")

Date_text = Label(text="Date").grid(row=0, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
ExistingCardType_text = Label(text="Existing Card Type").grid(row=3, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
RequestedCardType_text = Label(text="Requested Card Type").grid(row=8, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
Name_text = Label(text="Name").grid(row=12, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
IDCard_text = Label(text="ID Card No.").grid(row=14, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
Address_text = Label(text="Address").grid(row=16, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
Island_text = Label(text="Island").grid(row=18, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)
PhoneNo_text = Label(text="Phone No.").grid(row=20, sticky = W, pady = 3, padx = 3)

Date = StringVar()
ExistingCardType = StringVar()
ExistingCardType.set("Visa Card Debit")
RequestedCardType = StringVar()
RequestedCardType.set("Master Card Debit")
Name = StringVar()
IDCard = StringVar()
Address = StringVar()
Island = StringVar()
PhoneNo = StringVar()

Date_entry = Entry(textvariable=Date, width=30).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
ECT_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Visa", variable=ExistingCardType, value="Visa Debit Card").grid(row=3, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
ECT_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Master", variable=ExistingCardType, value="Master Debit Card").grid(row=4, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
ECT_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Amex", variable=ExistingCardType, value="Amex Debit Card").grid(row=5, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
RCT_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Visa", variable=RequestedCardType, value="Visa Debit Card").grid(row=8, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
RCT_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Master", variable=RequestedCardType, value="Master Debit Card").grid(row=9, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
RCT_rbtn = Radiobutton(app, text="Amex", variable=RequestedCardType, value="Amex Debit Card").grid(row=10, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 1)
Name_entry = Entry(textvariable=Name, width=30).grid(row=12, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
IDCard_entry = Entry(textvariable=IDCard, width=30).grid(row=14, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
Address_entry = Entry(textvariable=Address, width=30).grid(row=16, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
Island_entry = Entry(textvariable=Island, width=30).grid(row=18, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 2)
PhoneNo_entry = Entry(textvariable=PhoneNo, width=30).grid(row=20, column=1, sticky = W, pady = 2)

button1 = Button(app, text="Generate Letter", command=save_info, width="42", height="1", bg="white")
button2 = Button(app, text="About", command=about, width="42", height="1", bg="white")

button1.place(x=5, y=330)
button2.place(x=5, y=365)


mainloop()
```

Comment: The most ugly issue with this code is that it depends on the existence of `r'C:\Users\Pain\Desktop\data\New folder'`. This code shouldn't work for any user who's name isn't "Pain", and, and, and...

Comment: Try to use relative paths for your data files so that accessing them is not user/system dependent.